# Which is more efficient coding?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a bible project and I need some inputs from experts to determine which is faster and more efficient in displaying results in the page.

My Bible table contains only 3 fields at the moment? id, verse_code, and verse_content.

For me to be able to display appropriate Bible Book and verse in word (ex. Genesis 1:1), I am doing switch-case statement on verse_code that includes 66 cases something like...

```
select (verse_code)
{
case 1: echo "Genesis";
case 2: echo "Exodus";
...
case 66: echo "Revelation";
}
```

I can keep it this way or I can add new column **book_name** and input book name of each corresponding verse. This will be equivalent to 31,103 rows.

Performance wise, which is faster between these 2 approach. Shall I keep my case statement of shall I input the book name for 31,103 rows?

Test code is here. 
http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test.html to use it, try entering Gen x:x where x is chapter and verse and first 3 letters of book. Sample: Gen 1:1 or Exo 2:2

The textbox is located at the bottom left

Thanks

Comment: Use array instead of switch case.

Comment: @twaddington <insert C/C++ old/new testament joke here>

Comment: php with mysql. here is the working demo using case select http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test.html @nhahtdh what do you mean use array? can you explain further?

Comment: Thanks Charles. I've re-tagged your post so you should get some more views. You might want to post some more code so we can give you better advice.

Comment: @Charles Wayne: This does not make any sense. No numbers should appear, and you don't need to use a `case` statement. Issue a `SELECT` and iterate through the results to print them.

Comment: @reinierpost I don't need to print them all at once. It is use to determine which book needs to be displayed. The project only display one verse at a time. If I iterate it, it will be generated all when I only need one. Forgive me if I am not making sence as I am starting off with this programming.

Comment: You can just do a MySQL select to return a single result: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 12;`

Comment: That is what I am currently using but the table contains only coded book,chapter, and verse. I need to test those codes using select case and display the word "Genesis" if user requested for the book genesis. if user requested for example Gen 1:1, the actual result from database is 101001001 (book1, chapter1, verse1)  plus the content

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use a lookup table with your queries, you're doing a roundtrip to the database anyway and for a database joining data like this is what it's designed for:

```
CREATE TABLE verses (verse_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,book_id INT NOT NULL, chapter INT NOT NULL,verse INT NOT NULL, verse_content TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE books(book_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,book_name VARCHAR(100)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Here with the verses table you see a book_id field that serves as a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to books (so you're certain it links to an existing book) and that you can henceforth use in a query to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) the data from verses together with book_name from books.

You could then look it up with query conditions that specify that books book_id must be the one you find in verses and your query will automatically return the correct book title.

```
 SELECT book_name,chapter,verse,verse_content FROM verses,books WHERE books.book_id = verses.book_id;
```

[Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) are one of those great SQL concepts that really empower your grasp over your data, this [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by Jeff Atwood will give you a good and clear idea what they could mean to you. I really recommend you look into it. :)

As an added bonus, since you probably aren't writing this just for your own use, abstracting the visualised data from your code by putting it in the database allows you to hand over this aspect (data entry and data correction) to other people that can be totally ignorant of (the underlying) coding.

Do you want people to have to alter your source code should you make a typo and call it Potter instead of Peter or will it be safer to give them a nice interface away from your code to allow them to change it to Peter?

It would also allow you to distribute the work over more people by having them all insert data without interfering with each other or with your code.